# MapBasic - Convert Excel date to MapInfo date

Tags: date, date-formatting, mapinfo, map-basic

If I have a table of Excel dates:

```
Date
-------
44197
44202
44272
44270
44241
44201
44206
```

How do I convert this into the MapInfo date format?

```
Date
20210101
20210106
20210317
20210315
20210214
20210105
20210110
```

Using MapBasic.

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick:

```
Update tableName set Date = StringToDate("01/01/1900")+(Date-2)
```